# Included columns are used in Seek operator

Tags: sql-server, indexing, statistics, sql-execution-plan

Consider a table with two non clustered index, and query:

```
1 INDEX_1 on table (column1, column2, column3)
2 INDEX_2 on table (column1) INCLUDED (column2, column3)

    SELECT column3
    FROM   table
    WHERE  column1 = 100 columnn2 =  100
```

For some reason, SQL server uses `INDEX_2`.
Execution plan for boths indexes are the same(besides object in Seek operator)
Also, the logical reads times are the same for boths.
How is it possible to perform seek operator with such conditions on `INDEX_2`, if index is not sorted by `column2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is it possible to perform seek operator with such conditions on INDEX_2, if index is not sorted by column2

An Index Seek seeks to a location in an index, but then may scan from that point along the leaf-level pages, which are stored in a doubly-linked list following the index sort order.

So it's really more of a Seek+Scan.  You'll see the same plan when selecting from a clustered index, because an index with included columns is kind of a miniature clustered index.

eg in Adventureworks

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, *
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE SalesOrderID = 43892
  AND ProductID = 758
```

will give you an Index Seek that reads multiple rows:

[image]

Seeking to the first page that contains a row for that SalesOrderID, and then scanning until it locates all the rows with that ProductID.  When the operator finds a page with a different SalesOrderID, it's done.

But If (column1, column2, column3) is the clustered index key, the query would be a single-row Seek.   All non-unique non-clustered indexes will have all the clustered index columns added as index key columns, and will physically be stored as a unique index.

Comment: I am on 100% have the same opinion. But In my case, I have all time number of rows read =1. How sql on during the scan step could return a desire item only with 1 row read

Comment: If (column1, column2, column3) is the clustered index key, that would explain it, because all non-unique non-clustered indexes will have all the clustered index columns added as index key columns, and will physically be stored as a unique index.

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft You are on 100% right, I was confused since my clustered index is not build on primary key. Please update your answer and I wil mark your answer as the best.

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft Could you please share with me any documentation about this case. I would like to have the better understanding how the index look like

Comment: That's considered "internals" so it's not documented officially, but you can read more about it here: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/nonclustered-indexes-lookup-key-btree/

Comment: Does I understand it properly: columns of clustered index are key of non clustered index,  not like included ?

Comment: If we consider two clustered indexes: (column1, column2 ) and (column2). Will be the number of page for the non clustered index the same for two types of clustered index?

Comment: The non-clustered indexes will have slightly fewer pages if the row locator is narrower.

Comment: A table can have only one clustered index.

Comment: Yes, I mean another:1 clustered(id1, id2), nonclustered(id3); 2 clustered(id1, id2), nonclustered (id3,id1). Are the any diff between 1 and 2?@ david-browne-microsoft

Comment: Those non-clustered indexes will be physically identical, stored as a unique nonclustered index with (id3,id1,id2) as the key columns, and (id3,id1,id2) on the leaf pages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224124/discussion-between-basil-kosovan-and-david-browne-microsoft).